# Rename all workbooks in folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rename all workbooks in a folder, based on the value of a cell in each file (basically reports dates). The xls files are saved from the internet in a folder. I wrote the code below but it's not working... workbooks.open fail and wb.name seems to not work either.

```
Sub openrenamebook()

Dim FileExtension As String, FilesInFolder As String
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook

FileExtension = "*xls"

FolderPath = "N:\MyFolder\"

FilesInFolder = Dir(FolderPath & FileExtension)

Do While FilesInFolder <> ""
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderPath & FilesInFolder, ReadOnly:=False)
 wb.Name = Mid(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value, 38, 2)
 wb.Close True
 FilesInFolder = Dir
 Set wb = Nothing

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What error is raised? When `.Open` fails what is the value of `FolderPath & FilesInFolder`?

Comment: When trying to compile, on wb.Name I have a" Compile error: Can't assign to read-only property" so the macro is not compiled at all

Comment: It may be a problem that FolderPath is declared as "N:\MyFolder\" and used again in FilesInFolder that way the Filename is :N:\MyFolder\N:\MyFolder\.xlsx (for a sample Fileextension)

Comment: @Oldcastle is correct. See my answer below

Comment: Thanks everyone, found the solution to my problem (mostly using Jiminy Cricket answer), but the first file was corrupted so... don't know how to catch this, but works perfect on "normal" files.
Thanks all contributors

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename a file by changing the Workbook Name property. But you can use the FileSystemObject.

A reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime is required for this code to work.

I cannot fully test because I do not know what file paths are specified in your worksheet. It assumes they're valid

```
Sub Test()
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim FileItem As File
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strRenameValue As String

    FolderPath = "N:\MyFolder\"
    'Loop Files
    For Each FileItem In FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileItem.Path)
        'Get The Value With Which To Rename The Workbook
        strRenameValue = Mid(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value, 38, 2)
        'You shouldn't need to save?
        wb.Close False
        'Now That The File Is Closed, Rename It
        FileItem.Name = strRenameValue
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next FileItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had an error on the dim FSO but activated the appropriate library. Now I get an error on the .Open it says the file doesn't exist (runtime 1004) check spelling etc but I tripled checked and it exists

Comment: Apologies, it should be FileItem.Path I've edited my answer

Comment: It's worth noting as well that when you rename the file, you'll only want to specify the file name and the extension - the folder name isn't required

Comment: VBA's `name oldpath as newpath` can do the same without the need for the FSO at all

Comment: I've learned something new there, thanks. In my personal code I use a custom Class which calls APIs for dealing with files - there's a huge performance boost

Comment: Thanks, I updated and on the row workbooks.open it failed (error Method open of object workbooks failed, I checked and FileItem.Path has the expected value (for the first file in the folder)

Comment: Thanks everyone again. Just read the comment on name oldpath as newpath  would you have an example I could adapt ?

Comment: code presumes all files in directory are excel workbooks - are they?

Answer (score 0):

Since you plan to rename the files, I would suggest that you start by loading all  the names into an array before renaming the files, in order to get coherent values from `Dir`.
I do that using the following function:

```
Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant
'   Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec
'   If no matching files are found, it returns False

    Dim FileArray() As Variant
    Dim FileCount As Integer
    Dim FileName As String

    On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

    FileCount = 0
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
    If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

    'Loop until no more matching files are found
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
        FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    GetFileList = FileArray
    Exit Function

    '   Error handler
NoFilesFound:
    GetFileList = False
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but how do I get the full list ? the function is private, and I still have trouble opening files, would it be better to have a "dummy" excel file ?

Comment: @iDevlop, nice function. Should be fine in >99% of cases, only thought for improvement is perhaps getting a file count first, then resizing the array up front? That redim preserve is expensive if there are a lot of files

Comment: @Oldcastle I removed the 'Private'. It's stored that way in my toolbox.bas library, and I have the habit to remove the Private only if I need to use the function.

Comment: Rather than resizing the array, use `Split`:  `Public Function EnumerateFiles(sDirectory As String, Optional sFileSpec As String = "*", Optional InclSubFolders As Boolean = True) As Variant: EnumerateFiles = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & sDirectory & "*." & sFileSpec & """ " & IIf(InclSubFolders, "/S ", "") & "/B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "."): End Function`.  Can then call using: `Sub Test(): Dim a As Variant: a = EnumerateFiles("C:\Path To Folders\", "xls*"): End Sub`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Nice functon, but after testing, I find my version much faster. Yours also opens up a command window for a small time, which I dont really like.

Comment: I've never really timed it - just assumed it was faster when there's lots of files.  I'll have to do some testing now.  With the `Dir` approach maybe using a collection instead.  No need to resize or keep track of the count then.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses a separate instance for speed (I did consider using ADO instead).

Also ensures only Excel files are opened and that the new filename is valid (I do assume that you have a valid suffix file type, ie *.xlsx* in your cell names)

```
Sub openrenamebook()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim FileExtension As String
Dim FilesInFolder As String
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim strRenameValue As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

With xlApp
    .Visible = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

FileExtension = "*.xls*"
FolderPath = "c:\temp\"
FilesInFolder = Dir(FolderPath & FileExtension)

Do While Len(FilesInFolder) > 0
   Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FilesInFolder)
   On Error Resume Next
   strRenameValue = Mid$(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value, 38, 2)
   On Error GoTo 0
   wb.Close False
   If Len(strRenameValue) > 0 Then Name FolderPath & FilesInFolder As FolderPath & strRenameValue
   Set wb = Nothing
   FilesInFolder = Dir
Loop

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```